# Is there any liquid that can replace water?

Tags: molecular-biology

I understand this is a little futuristic but water freezes and damages cell causing cryostasis yet a reality. Is there any liquid that can be added to the blood synthetic or not that either plants and animals can live on instead of water? Synthetic water?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Water is essential both as a solvent and major component of biochemical reactions.

Imagining 'alien life' not based on water, not based on carbon, etc., is only for speculation and science fiction.